# Creating indented header for \subsubsection in document

Tags: sectioning

I have the following setup for my titles. However, I cannot figure out how I can create a slightly indented title for the \subsubsection. Following is the code that I used, however, that doesn't seem to work. Anybody has an idea what the fix could be? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
        
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\chapter}{\centering\bfseries}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\itshape\bfseries}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}{1em}{} %this needs to be indented from the left
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\bfseries}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\chapter{X}
\section{A}
\subsection{B}
\subsubsection{C}
\paragraph{D}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling the example? First of all, ensure that no errors are raised. Then look for the documentation of `\titleformat` and of `\titlespacing`.

Comment: @egreg: I did compile it, however, it doesn't show me the subsubsection as an indented header. Other, there are no errors in the code itself.

Comment: ``! Package titlesec Error: Not allowed in `easy' settings.`` is an error message due to `\titleformat*{\chapter}` that's not allowed. Second error: `Runaway argument?
{\fontsize {12{14\selectfont } \titleformat *{\section }{\bfseries }{\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \ttl@format@si was complete.`

Comment: Sorry, my code was wrong but is now adjusted. Now, when I compile, it gives me still no indented header.

Comment: I still get two errors. Anyway, I already advised you to look for `\titlespacing`.